# Overlapping time series with R

Tags: r, time-series, ggplot2

My data frame df has these columns: token (a factor), date (a POSIXct), an count (an integer).

```
> head(df,3)
  token       date             count
1 foo  10/1/2011 12:00:00 AM     6
2 bar 10/12/2011 12:00:00 AM    24
3 baz 10/14/2011 12:00:00 AM     4
```

I know how plot a time series for a factor 'foo', e.g. `qplot(date, count, data=df[df$token == "foo",], geom="line");`. But how do I plot the time series of all factors into the same chart, each factor line with a different color.

How do I plot the daily counts for the values in the token columns (e.g., foo, bar, baz) against and the dates?  Basically counts on the y-axis and dates on the x-axis.

Comment: Must it be in ggplot - lattice allowed?

Comment: I didn't know about lattice. That would be fine.

Comment: Could you attach some kind of result picture (maybe by hand or using any graphic editor)? I do not know about the others, but for me it is unclear what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I would vote for some sample data. :)

Comment: BTW, are you looking for something like this? http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8161901/frekv_dat_sites_taxa.png

Comment: Yes, Roman. Exactly like that. I was able to get something very close to what I wanted: http://i.imgur.com/5b6gQ.png Using this: `qplot(date,count,data=df,group=token, color=token, geom="line");`  I still would like to figure out how to have the x-axis start with the month of August. I don't know why the plot started on July since I don't have any data on it.

Comment: What `class` is `df$date`? Character or a `POSIX*`?

Comment: `class(df$date)` returns `[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"`

Comment: I would have to be persuaded that R/ggplot2 just makes dates up. :)

Comment: True. Found the outlier data observations :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hard question to answer without a reproducible example, but something like `qplot(date,count,data=df,group=token)` may work.

Comment: `by`? `facets` maybe? Or maybe the OP wants `group`, to keep them all on the same panel?

Comment: @joran: Good call, I meant `group` not `by`.

Comment: It would make sense to have panel for each token level, though.

Comment: thanks! that's very close to what i want. it that generates a plot with dots for each date point, right? This is what I get: http://imgur.com/fFVdi  Now, could each factor be a different color? Your plot gave me this:

Comment: @andresmh: I don't have R right now, so I'm working off memory here, but try adding `color=token`.  You could also do `facet=~token`.  There's also a way to change the plot style from points to lines, but I forget how.  Check out the ggplot 2 site: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I wanted: qplot(date,count,data=df,group=token, color=token, geom="line");

Answer (score 3):

I have a data.frame that looks like this (I used `reshape::melt` to get data from wide to long format):

```
> head(big)
             Taxa    variable value sites
1      Coleoptera 15.4.-30.4.    92   Low
2      Orthoptera 15.4.-30.4.     2   Low
3     Heteroptera 15.4.-30.4.    NA   Low
4       Homoptera 15.4.-30.4.    NA   Low
5 Auchenorrhyncha 15.4.-30.4.    NA   Low
6      Neuroptera 15.4.-30.4.    NA   Low
```

And I used ggplot2 code below to create this image[image]

```
ggplot(big, aes(x = droplevels(Taxa), fill = sites, y = value)) + 
        geom_bar(position = "dodge") + 
        facet_wrap(~ variable) +
        scale_x_discrete(name = "Taksoni") +
        scale_y_continuous(name = "Abundanca") +
        scale_fill_discrete(name = "Vzorčna \n mesta") +
        opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle = 90))
```